# Estructura de tablas MySQL diferente a lo habitual

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

Bien, les cuento, actualmente estoy estudiando, recién acabo de terminar la clase de base de datos, ustedes sabrán que en las universidades se nos enseña a hacer las tablas de una base de datos (mayormente MySQL) de la siguiente manera:
**tbl_empleados**
Contiene las columnas **ID, Nombre, Apellido, Nacimiento, Genero, Estado Civil, Puesto de Trabajo etc**.
Es decir, una tabla conteniendo absolutamente toda la información relacionada a ella y alguna que otra llave foránea por allí, como puede ser el caso de Estado Civil y Puesto de Trabajo.

Ahora bien, cuales serian los PROS y CONTRAS de una estructura de la siguiente manera:
**tbl_empleados**
Únicamente conteniendo el **ID**
**tbl_empleados_nombre**
Únicamente conteniendo el **ID (para relacionar con tbl_empleados)** y **nombre**
**tbl_empleados_apellido**
Únicamente conteniendo el **ID (para relacionar con tbl_empleados)** y **apellido**
Y así sucesivamente.
Es decir, **dividirlo todo, tener una tabla para cada dato de una entidad completa**, en este caso, la entidad Empleado.

Cuales serian los **PROS y CONTRAS** de hacer este tipo de base de datos?
Sin contar claro que al final de mi proyecto puedo llegar a tener **cientos (o incluso miles) de tablas**, cuando en realidad si hubiese usado la estructura convencional que me enseñaron en la universidad solo tuviese algunas **decenas de tablas** ni en cuanto al mantenimiento de la misma, ya que se al tener tremenda cantidad de tablas yo se que el mantenimiento va a ser pesado.
Me refiero a que si esto puede llegar a tener un impacto significativo **(positivo o negativo)** en cuanto al rendimiento de mi aplicación web si esta llegase a tener un gran volumen de datos. Si al partir toda la base de datos en tablas con pocos campos (en lugar de tener una tabla con muchos campos) afecta la lectura y escritura, etc.
Agradecería mucho su opinión al respecto de alguien con experiencia en el área.
Gracias.

Comment: "PROS Y CONTRAS", basada en opiniones personales, re comiendo [esta lectura](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Es mala idea según la [normalización de bases de datos](https://guru99.es/database-normalization/) de cualquier manera Lee lo que te puso @gabrielcoronel para que sepas cómo elaborar preguntas en el futuro ya que está es posible que se cierre.

Answer (score 0):

Dado que el OP pregunta por criterios técnicos y no opiniones personales, no tengo inconveniente en responder a esta pregunta. Al fin y al cabo el modelado, por las diferentes soluciones que puede admitir, siempre sería objeto de debate y entiendo que sepamos apreciar las ventajas de cada opción sin que el debate sea excesivamente extenso e improductivo.

En respuesta a tu pregunta, da la sensación de que quieres llevar al límite el concepto de particionamiento:

https://www.sqlshack.com/es/particionamiento-de-tablas-de-bases-de-datos-en-sql-server/

Algo así como superespecializar cada tabla.

Pues, salvo por la incomodidad que comentas de tener que recurrir a varios `JOIN` para cada cada `SELECT` y `UPDATE`, así como a varios `INSERT` por cada nuevo registro (lo que sin duda afectará al rendimiento), tampoco le veo ningún inconveniente en cuanto a normalización.

El hecho de particionar una tabla no tiene por qué generar duplicidades.

Pero mejor no lo hagas, no me gustaría encontrarme nunca un diagrama de ese tipo. No me quiero ni imaginar la cantidad de horas que requeriría su mantenimiento.